# R package (renv) folder is repeating in R library folder

Tags: r, directory, renv

I noticed that when I use renv, the renv folder in my library is super messed up. The contents of the folder is as follows:

\?\C:\Users\User\R\renv\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\renv\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library\R-4.2\x86_64-w64-mingw32.renv-copy-3fec2cd46d84\library .... (repeats presumably forever).

I tried to uninstall the package and reinstall, but to no avail.

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it can be symlinks no real folders. perhaps you're init renv in the wrong current directory

Comment: Can you please file a bug report at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues with some more information?